# ClearCase: how to find version history of each document in a folder

Tags: testing, clearcase

I am a newbie to Rational ClearCase. Can you guide me how can I get version history (report) of each document in a folder say 'ABC'.

I need a report which details version history, (history of change details if possible)

Please enlighten me on this.

Thanks

Comment: What platform ? Do you want a GUI or command line solution ?

Comment: I need GUI based solution prefrentilally

Comment: Windows or other OS ? For Windows just right-click on the file in Explorer then ClearCase -> History

Answer (score 7):

The two usual tools for getting a "report" on an element (file or directory) on ClearCase are:

- lsvtree (version tree)

```
    cleartool lsvtree (-graph) /path/to/myView/MyVob/.../myFile
```

- lshistory (history)

```
    cleartool lshistory (-graph) /path/to/myView/MyVob/.../myFile
```

Both will launch a graphical interface if you include `-graph` in your command.

Comment: @Cartman: whenever you need to examine the history and see the evolution between versions.

Comment: @Cartman: the simplest way to execute them is to be directly in the parent directory of the file from which you want to see the history. By if you have their full path, then you can execute those commands from anywhere within a shell session.